# Проблема с голосовым ассистентом

Tags: python

Всем привет! Я имею проблему с голосовым ассистентом при запросе не реагирует на запросы. Но это не ошибка потому что она не отображается .

```
import os
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pyttsx3
import datetime

# settings
opts = {
"alias": ('fox', '', '', '', '', '',
          '', '', '', '', ''),
"tbr": ('say', 'tell', 'show', 'how much', 'say'),
"cmds": {
    "ctime": ('current time', 'now is the time', 'what time is it'),
    "radio": ('turn on the music', 'play the radio', 'turn on the radio'),
    "stupid1": ('tell a joke', 'make me laugh', 'you know jokes')
   }
}


# the functions
def speak(what):
print(what)
speak_engine.say(what)
speak_engine.runAndWait()
speak_engine.stop()


def callback(recognizer, audio):
try:
    voice = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN").lower()
    print("[log] Recognized: " + voice)

    if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
        # turn to fox
        cmd = voice

        for x in opts['alias']:
            cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

        for x in opts['tbr']:
            cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

        # recognize and execute the command
        cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
        execute_cmd(cmd['cmd'])

except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("[log] Voice not recognized!")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("[log] Unknown error, check internet!")


def recognize_cmd(cmd):
RC = {'cmd': '', 'percent': 0}
for c, v in opts['cmds'].items():

    for x in v:
        vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
        if vrt > RC['percent']:
            RC['cmd'] = c
            RC['percent'] = vrt

return RC


 def execute_cmd(cmd):
if cmd == 'ctime':
    # say current time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    speak("Now " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))

elif cmd == 'radio':
    # play radio
    os.system("D:\\Music")

elif cmd == 'stupid1':
    # tell a joke
    speak("My developer did not teach me jokes ... Ha ha ha")

else:
    print('Command not recognized, retry!')


# launch
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

with m as source:
   r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()


# Only if you have installed voice for speech synthesis!
voices = speak_engine.getProperty('voices')
speak_engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)

# forced cmd test
speak("My developer did not teach me jokes ...")

# speak("Good afternoon lord")
# speak("Fox is listening")

# stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
# while True: time.sleep(0.1) # infinity loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка есть, у тебя не стоят отступы с 23 по 26 строку. Для phyton это важно.

Неправильно:

```
def speak(what):
print(what)
speak_engine.say(what)
speak_engine.runAndWait()
speak_engine.stop()
```

Правильно:

```
def speak(what):
    print(what)
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()
```

[image: Вот ошибка]

Такие же ошибки во всем коде. Вот твой исправленный код:

```
import os
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pyttsx3
import datetime

#settings
opts = {
    "alias": ('fox'),
    "tbr": ('say', 'tell', 'show', 'how much', 'say'),
    "cmds": {
        "ctime": ('current time', 'now is the time', 'what time is it'),
        "radio": ('turn on the music', 'play the radio', 'turn on the radio'),
        "stupid1": ('tell a joke', 'make me laugh', 'you know jokes')
    }
}


#the functions
def speak(what):
    print(what)
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()


def callback(recognizer, audio):
    voice = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN").lower()
    print("[log] Recognized: " + voice)

    try:

        if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
            # turn to fox
            cmd = voice

            for x in opts['alias']:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            for x in opts['tbr']:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            # recognize and execute the command
            cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
            execute_cmd(cmd['cmd'])

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("[log] Voice not recognized!")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("[log] Unknown error, check internet!")


def recognize_cmd(cmd):
    RC = {'cmd': '', 'percent': 0}
    for c, v in opts['cmds'].items():
        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > RC['percent']:
                RC['cmd'] = c
                RC['percent'] = vrt

    return RC


def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd == 'ctime':
        # say current time
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        speak("Now " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))

    elif cmd == 'radio':
        # play radio
        os.system("D:\\Music")

    elif cmd == 'stupid1':
        # tell a joke
        speak("My developer did not teach me jokes ... Ha ha ha")

    else:
        print('Command not recognized, retry!')


#launch
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

with m as source:
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()


#Only if you have installed voice for speech synthesis!
voices = speak_engine.getProperty('voices')
speak_engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)

#forced cmd test
speak("My developer did not teach me jokes ...")

#speak("Good afternoon lord")
#speak("Fox is listening")

#stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
#while True: time.sleep(0.1) # infinity loop
```

Но чтобы он работал нормально, убери # перед последними двумя строками